# Unirulled subvariety of Fano manifold containing a general surface not intersecting a given subvariety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^N$ be a smooth Fano variety of dimension $n \ge 5$ and $U$ be an open subset of $X$ whose complement has co-dimension at least $4$.  Let $Y$ be the intersection of $X$ with $n-2$ general hyperplanes. Then $Y$ is smooth projective surface  contained in $U$. For each $x \in Y$, let $l_x$ be a general rational curve though $x$ and contained in $U$ and $Z = \cup_{x \in Y}l_x$. Let $\overline{Z}$ be the closure of $Z$ in $X$.

Question: Can we say that  $\overline{Z} \subset U$ ?

Comment: No, we cannot say that.  Of course $\overline{Z}$ is the image in $X$ of a rational "fibration" over a dense open subset of $Y$.  The general fiber maps to a general (hence free) rational curve in $U$.  However, there will be fibers that are *not* general as well.  Without further hypotheses on $X$, we can say no more.

Comment: I did not get your point. Could you please explain little more ? In the construction of $Z$, I am taking one general rational curve for each point of $Y$. Hence the dimension of $\overline{Z}$ is $3$. Can we say something when Picard rank of $X$ is one and a general rational curve through each point of $U$ is free ?

Comment: Could you please explain a little more?  How are you choosing a "general" rational curve for each point of $Y$?  The variety $Y$ is proper.  The set of "general" rational curves is very much not proper.  The most straightforward interpretation of what you wrote is that you have a family of general rational curves that intersect $Y$, but where the base of your family is not proper.  When you take the closure of that base in an appropriate parameter space of curves, very likely the closure intersects the locus of curves that are not "general" (i.e., not free).

Comment: Given a point $x \in Y$ consider $K_x$, the minimal rational curves passing through $x$. Choose a general point in $K_x$ for each $x$. In other words, we have a set of rational curves indexed by $Y$ and $Z$ is the union of all such rational curves. I am considering $Z$ as just a set. Now we take the closure of it which is now a subvariety of $X$ of dimension $3$.

Comment: Since complement of $U$ has co-dimension at least $4$, a general $3$ dimensional subvariety of $X$ will be contained in $U$.

Comment: If you just choose a "set-theoretic" section of the $K_x$ fibration over $Y$, the Zariski closure $\overline{Z}$ is almost certainly all of $X$.

Comment: For the moment assume that $K_x$ are complete for all $x \in U$ and have same dimension $d-2$, where $d$ is the minimal degree. Let $g: \{0\} \times K \to X$ be the  restriction of the evaluation map $f: \mathbb{P}^1 \times K \to X$, where $K$ is a minimal rational component. Now take the inverse image of $Y$ under$g$.  Then the inverse image has dimension $d$ and $\overline{Z} \subset f(g^{-1}(Y))$ which has dimension $d+1$. Then how can the closure of $Z$ be all of $X$ ?

Comment: Your hypotheses are invalid.

Comment: Why are they invalid ? It is known that for a general $x \in X, K_x$ is complete. For example if $X$ is the moduli space of vector bundles on curves of rank $r$ and degree $m$, where $r$ and $m$ are co-prime. The $(1, 1)$ stable bundles are dense whose complement has high co-dimension. The  Hecke curves passing through a $(1, 1)$ stable bundles are minimal rational curves and the variety of Hecke curves through a $(1, 1)$ stable bundle is complete.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139792/discussion-between-lapras-and-jason-starr).

Comment: You can send me an e-mail to discuss this further.